Extreme points of matrices with least eigenvalue
Given $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},0 < \epsilon < 1/n$:

Define matrix set
$$
M:=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times
   n}:X=X^T,\text{tr}(X)=1,\lambda_n(X)\geq\epsilon\}
$$
$$
\mbox{Here}\quad\lambda_1(X)\geq\lambda_2(X)\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n(X)
$$
are the eigenvalues of $X$. And we have
$$
\lambda_2(X),\cdots,\lambda_n(X)\geq\epsilon,\lambda_1(X)\leq 1-(n-1)\epsilon
$$
Obviously $M$ is a convex set. What are the extreme points of $M$ ?.
I think for matrix $A$, if
$$
\lambda_2(A)=\cdots=\lambda_n(A)=\epsilon,\lambda_1(A)=1-(n-1)\epsilon,
$$
then $A$ is one extreme point of $M$.
Because if
$$
A = pB+(1-p)C,
$$
where $0\leq p\leq 1,B,C\in M$, if $x_i$ is the eigenvector of $A$ of eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, for $2\leq i\leq n$,
$$
\epsilon = x_i^TAx_i = px_i^TBx_i+(1-p)x_i^TCx_i\geq\epsilon,
$$
so $x_i$ is the eigenvector
of both $B$ and $C$.
The same for $x_1$. So we have $A=B=C$. Are
there any other extreme points of $M$?


Those are all the extreme points for $n\ge 2$.
(for $n=1$ the set is just the point $1$).
Let $A\in M$ where $\lambda_1<1-(n-1)\epsilon$. This implies that $\lambda_2>\epsilon$. Suppose $A=QDQ^T$ is its eigendecomposition with $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal of $D$ in order. Then
$B=QD_1Q^T$, $C=QD_2Q^T$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ coincide with $D$ on all elements except the first two.
In particular, $D_1$ has as first two elements $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$. Instead $D_2$ has as first two elements $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2+\epsilon$ and $2\lambda_2 -\epsilon$. Both $B$ and $C$ are still in $M$ and if $p=1/2$, then $A=pB+(1-p)C$.
